# Calling background before @Setup

Tags: karate

We recently added the @setup call to capture a list of items to delete, if present on the test account; but the background, which defines a variable that is used in a URL parameter and results in a `ReferenceError: "variableName" is not defined`.
Making the same request outside a @setup structure works just fine, as the URL parameter is populated via the background logic.

Is this by design, that @setup is called before background?  If so, how would you suggest we work around this or could this be changed to be evaluated after the background.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design as described [here](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1905#issuecomment-1203597442).

- Option 1: variables defined in `karate-config.js` should still be available to the `@setup` routine
- Option 2: just declare the variable using `def` at the start of the `@setup` routine instead of the `Background`

Comment: While I see the third comment of the ticket, `the Background will NOT run for the @setup scenario. yes this is a bit inconsistent, but this is the best I could come up with. yes, @setup is "special"`, I also see the following: `in other words, the setup() has only one role: generate the scenarios, and that is it. if there is common code for each Scenario, that should be in the Background. and concepts such as callonce are now the same as before`.  Since the @setup is ONLY to generate data for the scenario, and values in the background are common code, @setup would make sense to use that info.

Comment: @mike the design is set and can't be changed, and IMHO does not need to be changed. here is a suggestion: create a reusable feature that can be used (called) by both the background and the `@setup` and that should solve your problem. and - repeating some code in both the background and the `@setup` is also a valid solution