How do I pass parameter when using karate.setupOnce() or karate.setup()
I'm trying to pass a specific parameter to a setup, but don't know how to do it properly. I've tried to do the following code:
`Feature: test
@setup=try
Scenario: run before
    * def run = "test"
    * print "running in the streets"
    * print parameter

Scenario Outline: run
    * def setup = karate.setupOnce("try") { parameter: <params> }
    * print setup.run
    * print user
    Examples:
        | user | params |
        | "A"  | 1      |
        | "B"  | 2      |` 

There's a way to do this something like we can do to karate.call?

You cannot. The whole point of setup is to do some logic and generate the whole table of Examples data that now can be fed into a Scenario Outline.
Please read this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76320023/143475
So please reconsider who to write your tests. An explanation can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78673358/143475
